# Elastic Greeklish to Greek conversion

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am new to a elastic and I am trying to find a way to convert greeklish character to greek when the search executes.

e.g word "papoutsia" to be searched as "παπουτσια" (shoes)

Due to my search I found the following plugins:

- [elasticsearch-analysis-greeklish](https://github.com/skroutz/elasticsearch-analysis-greeklish)
- [elasticsearch-skroutz-greekstemmer](https://github.com/skroutz/elasticsearch-skroutz-greekstemmer)

Applied the filters to my index as the example but my queries still hit nothing.

Do I have to apply the filter some way in every query or do a special one?

Sorry I this question has a very large/broad answer to be given. 
I trying to figure how the whole filtering thing works for a couple of days to understand if I am even in the correct direction or have to find an other way for this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the intention of the [greeklish plugin / char filter](https://github.com/skroutz/elasticsearch-analysis-greeklish) is the inverse of what you want to achieve: 
Using this filter, you can retrieve greek text from a document, using a query that is written in latin characters ("greeklish").
So, for your example, you can add a document with the text `παπούτσια` and retrieve it using the terms `papoutsia`, `papoutsi`, etc.

We have prepared [a detailed text pipeline example](https://github.com/skroutz/elasticsearch-analysis-greeklish/wiki/A-full-example-of-a-greeklish-text-pipeline) in the repo's wiki for future reference.